# What is the standard way to install packages for Emacs?

Tags: package, package-repositories

There are several methods to install and manage packages for Emacs:

- package.el
- el-get
- use-package

What is the easiest way to install package? It seems package.el ships with the default Emacs installation.

I tried use-package, each time I start Emacs, it will take a few second to contact hosts like melpa...

Comment: I'm using package.el as it comes with (recent versions of) Emacs.  It only contacts repositories when you ask it to, so there's no cost to managing packages this way.

Comment: Package.el is the standard way and here is some help: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Package.el el-get is an alternative solution which existed before package.el and can still be complementary sometimes. Use-package is (correct me if I'm wrong) a macro around package.el.

Comment: Related thread: [What are the practical differences between the various Emacs Package Repositories?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/268/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-the-various-emacs-package-repositorie).

Comment: @Dan Thank you. That's highly valuable.

Comment: I'll put in a word for my package manager, [`straight.el`](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el), since I personally prefer it (obviously) to `package.el`. You can read the *extremely verbose* documentation to learn about the differences. I won't put this as an answer, since it doesn't answer your question: the **standard** package manager is `package.el`, whereas `straight.el` is almost certainly never going to be shipped with Emacs. Re: @Ehvince I've added functionality to `use-package` to allow using it with other package managers, including `straight.el`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you've answered your own question: `package.el` is the **standard** way to install packages, because it's built into Emacs 24.

Everything else is non-standard (and probably somewhat subjective. I manage most third-party libraries via `el-get`, personally).

Comment: you're right. The reason I ask this question is to find out what others use for package management. package.el mess up with the package `auto-complete`. (Maybe it's not package.el's fault). I tried use-pacakge and el-get, finally satisfied with el-get.

Comment: MELPA and MELPA-Stable are the best for vetted packages. El-Get is the best for things under your vetting.

Comment: @grettke After using different methods/repositories for a while, I begin to realize that your words is really invaluable: concise and to the point. Thank you!