# Transitioning to MELPA

Tags: package, package-repositories

It's time.  I've spent too long with too many pieces of elisp lying around in `site-lisp`, outdated until I manually grab a new copy.  I am new to the ELPA/MELPA/`package.el`/`el-get` world, but have determined (okay, maybe 90% confident) from emacswiki and [this excellent question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/268/2051) that MELPA is the way to go, but how, exactly do I do that?  There are some basic instructions for initial setup on the website, but it's not clear to me how I should migrate, and tell emacs:

- Which pieces to check on
- Where and how to store them
- What to do with my local copies

Comment: Just a general clarification. GNU Elpa and Melpa are not mutually exclusive, in fact, Melpa relies on you using GNU Elpa too. Also, `package.el` is not an alternative to the others, it is the library that allows you to interact with Melpa, GNU Elpa, Marmalade, and other such repos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Basic packages

The [basic way](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started) to use packages^(1) is pretty simple:

Add to your init file:

```
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
```

Then, run `M-x list-packages` to get the [package menu](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Menu.html#Package-Menu). From this menu, you can search for packages, view descriptions, install, uninstall, and update packages. Press `i` to mark a package for installation, `d` for marking a package for uninstallation (deletion), or `U` to mark all installed packages that can be upgraded for upgrading. Then, pressing `x` will perform these actions.

### Freedom from management

Using package installation will handle storing things for you; you don't have to worry about managing files or directories. Once you replace a locally-installed .el file with a package from a repository, you can get rid of the local file and the load instructions from your init file. You will need to keep any configuration of that package, however.

### Advanced packages

Other methods include things like [Cask](http://cask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which is a way of automating the management of installed packages. You have a file of packages you want installed, and you can have Cask do installations and upgrades automatically.

[1] Note that this way of dealing with packages is not specific to MELPA -- it will work with the GNU ELPA repo, or Marmalade -- you just have to find the proper location to add to `'package-archives`.

Comment: As a follow-up, finally did this last summer (so, five years too late) and 