# How can I change the installation folder for Melpa packages?

Tags: package-repositories

I have just started using Melpa, and I installed the first package. The package though goes to the folder

~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Pakcages/elpa/

but I would prefer if it went to my .emacs.d/packages folder.

Is there a way to do that or is it not advisable for some reason? If not advisable, is there a way to ensure that if I use another computer that I still have that package installed so that the configurations are the same?

This is what I put on my .emacs file to get Melpa working as per [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/15274/9416)

```
;; Package installation - MELPA
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to change the variable `package-user-dir`:

```
(setq package-user-dir "~/.emacs.d/packages")
```

Change this setting before calling `(package-initialize)` or anything involving loading or installing packages, but after `(require 'package)`.

How I found this:

I use [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm), which makes it easy to search through Emacs's functions and variables. I called `describe-variable` with `C-h v` and searched for `package dir`, and the variable came up. Without Helm, I would use the command `apropos-variable` and search for the same thing.

Comment: OK, that was superb! I really appreciate the last paragraph so that I can find my own answers in the future :)

Comment: @Vivi You're welcome! `apropos` is great, it's really a killer feature. To see all the `apropos-*` commands, try `C-h a apropos RET`

Comment: I always use M-x customize-apropos and I love it! I didn't know any others though so I will have a look now. I just installed Helm using Melpa and it went to the desired folder, ty!