# How to use the same elpa directory to download packages for different Emacs starter kits

Tags: package-repositories

I am using different Emacs starter kits. The problem is that each starter kit, I use different directories (for example, for prelude I use´.emacsPrelude.d´, for SciMax I use ´.emacsSciMax.d´) . But all starter kits shares a common directory inside the directories, which is called Elpa. I can't use the same directory because each has  different directory structure. Is there any Emacs command to define where Elpa packages will be installed? Or can I change the Elpa directory in my ´init.el´ file?

Comment: How about using a different `package-user-dir` for different setups.  When Emacs starts, it can ask you which starter kit / setup you want to use and then assign the corresponding `package-user-dir`.  You can take it one step further and even have different `user-emacs-directory` ... assigning the value on startup.

Comment: @lawlist, I found a similar question on [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16605/how-can-i-change-the-installation-folder-for-melpa-packages).  It looks ´package-user-dir´ right way to proceed. Could you elaborate a little bit about ´user-emacs-directory´. And how can I arrange my ´init´ file that Emacs ask me whict starter kit/ setup I want to use and then assign the corresponding ´package-user-dir´.

Comment: Here is a link to an example of what I had in mind in terms of Emacs asking the user which settings to load and adjusting the `package-user-dir` accordingly:  https://github.com/lawlist/countdown-timer  Changing the `user-emacs-directory` is something I do programmatically when using different computers and different operating systems ... because the paths will be different.

Comment: I like all of my stuff to be in one main folder so that I can easily backup and synchronize with other computers and handheld devices.  My main directory with all the stuff is `/Users/HOME/.0.data` and my Emacs installation and related Emacs-stuff is `/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs`.  I set the `user-emacs-directory` to `/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/` -- ensuring that it has a forward trailing slash .  My w32 virtual machine (Parallels) has an Emacs installation and I set the `user-emacs-directory` as `y:/.0.data/.0.emacs/`, which is a mapped to the host computer where I have all my Emacs-stuff.